# Deployment of Maven project to JBoss - noob question

Tags: java, maven, deployment, jboss, pom.xml

I think I generally understand the principles of Maven (I am a Maven noob).

When I launch the "package"-LifeCycle in IntelliJ, I can see that `POM.xml` is included in the created `*.jar` file. At this time, Maven has pulled all dependencies and put them into `.m2` folder. So far, so good.

**My question is:** what happens when I deploy this `*.jar` file to JBoss?

1. Will JBoss execute the `*.POM` again in order to get the same libraries to it's own maven-repository or will it use the `.m2` folder that is already in my user folder?
2. Will JBoss execute the POM at all? If yes, will it execute the whole POM or only the dependencies part?
3. If it is the case, when will the POM be executed? As soon as I put the `*.jar` in the deployment folder or when I launch the app first time?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to deploy war or jar? AFAIK if you want to package a jar file to webserver you need to declare it's dependencies in the pom war package.

Comment: Hi Erwin, 
first of all, thank you for your reply!
OK, I've got the point with war, but my focus was more on how JBoss deals with POM.xml (see questions 1-3) and what happens with POM.xml after putting a *.war - file into the auto-deployment folder

Comment: I assume you want to deploy war to JBoss? If so then you need to declare package as war in pom file so then maven will package as a war. Then jar dependencies will be included in the war file. Webservers (JBoss) never have anything to do with maven.